# Cut-off time two days later

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

In Datepicker i am trying to restrict selectable dates to sundays, and only if picked before 15:00 on the thursday. 
What am i doing wrong?, restricting to only sundays works, and cutoff time 15:00 works but the day before not two days before.

```
$( "#deliverysunday" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        beforeShowDay: function(date){ return [date.getDay() == 0,""]},
        minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 15 ? 2 : 0
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to ensure that the earliest possible date to be picked is the first Sunday that occurs no later than Thursday at 15:00.

The `minDate` option is going to control which date is the earliest selectable date; the logic to determine the cutoff time should go in your `beforeShowDay` option:

```js
$( "#deliverysunday" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  showWeek: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    return [isDateSelectable(date)];
  },
  minDate: 2
});


/**
 * Given a date, returns a boolean to indicate
 * whether the date should be selectable in a picker.
 * Tests the date according to the rules:
 *
 * - Is the date a Sunday?
 * - Is it currently before the cutoff time?
 */
function isDateSelectable(date) {
  // Cutoff interval = Sun@00:00 - Thu@15:00 = 57 hours
  var intervalInMillis = 57 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var now = new Date();
  var isPriorToInterval = now.getTime() < date.getTime() - intervalInMillis;

  // Is date a Sunday?
  var isSunday = date.getDay() === 0;

  return isSunday && isPriorToInterval;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<h1>Date picker example</h1>
<div id="deliverysunday"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Palpatim, after a few slight alterations (there are more than one delivery options) it works exactly the way i wanted.